# Какая разница между блокоми синхронизации с параметром this и отдельным объектом монитора?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Какая разница, между использованием в качестве монитора для блокировки объекта, сам объект:

```
MyClass {
    void m() {
        synchronized(this) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

И отдельный специально созданый объект-монитор:

```
MyClass {
    Object obj = new Object();
    void m() {
        synchronized(obj) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Что в каком случае блокируется и почему? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyClass {
    Boolean canBeWorked= true;
    List<Object> data = ...

    void setCanBeWorked(boolean value){
        //Берем блокировку по флагу, не давая во втором методе его читать или изменять
        synchronized(canBeWorked){
        //Меняем значение переменной
           canBeWorked = value;
        }

    }
    boolean add(Object obj) {
        //Не даем первому методу изменять флаг
        synchronized(canBeWorked){
          if (!canBeWorked){
              return false;
          }
        }
        //Берем блокировку по списку для добавления
        synchronized(data) {
            data.add(obj);
        }
    }

    Object getFirst(){
        synchronized(data){
            if (data.isEmpty()) return null;
            return data.get(0);
        }
    }
```

Вот вам пример, как вы и просили в коментариях. Естественно он с потолка и так писать не стоит, но синхронизацию демонстрирует.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А в чем отличие этого примера от первого? Мы просто заблокировали лист. В чем отличие в поведении такого кода от лока на одном объекте или синхронизации всего метода?

Comment: В приведенном пример представьте ситуацию, что есть у нас есть множество потоков, а код метода add более сложен и выполняется заметное количество времени. Если вы будете всегда брать блокировку по одному объекту, то пока будет выполняться метод add() в одном из потоков, все остальные при вызове, например setCanBeWorked() буду ждать когда он блокировку освободит, хотя работа с переменной canBeWorked уже возможно давно выполнена и не давать ее менять другим потока - глупо и очень накладно.

Comment: Вообще с синхронизацией надо быть очень аккуратными. synchronized не панацея и его нельзя бездумно тыкать где зря. Есть ReentrantLock, есть ReadWriteLock, StampedLock - все они помогают с синхронизацией, но имеют свою плюсы и минусы для разных ситуаций. Неправильная работа с синхронизацией, может привести от сильного уменьшения производительности вашего кода вплоть до Deadlock-ов

Answer (score 3):

- в первом случае блокировка будет по объекту у которого вызван метод
- во втором по отдельному объекту

Используя второй вариант можно синхронизировать несколько разных объектов используя один объект-монитор. Так же вы можете создать отдельные мониторы для разных методов. Например, один монитор на запись, другой на чтение.

Comment: >>>Так же вы можете создать отдельные мониторы для разных методов. Например, один монитор на запись, другой на чтение.<<< Это значит что если я создал отдельный монитор-объект и послал его во все блоки синхронизации в классе(один и тот-же), то эффект будет как от первого варианта?

Comment: да. но при использовании `wait/notify` нужно будет указывать правильный объект.

Comment: Тоесть если подводить итог то я правильно понимаю что:  при использовании this мы блокируем конкретный экземпляр класса целиком. При использовании лок-объекта мы блокируем только конкретный кусок кода которым он обрамлен? Тоесть если бы во втором примере были в классе еще методы (без синхронизации) то они были-бы доступны другим потокам. И общий принцип - один лок-объект = один поток который может зайти во все блокт синхронизации параметром в которых он указан?

Comment: @Павел комментарии не имеют такого веса как вопросы-ответы. Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

```
synchronized(this){}
```

Блокировка берется по текущему экземпляру класса. Равносильно объявлению метода как synchronized

```
synchronized(obj) {
            // do something...
        }
```

Берется по тому объекту, который вы указали

Использование блокировки по заданному объекту удобней в том плане, что вы в методе можете брать их и отпускать для разных объектов объявленных в этом классе которые вы синхронизируете. Т.е. например у вас есть два Map с которым вы работаете. Взяли блокировку по одному - поработали, отпустили, взяли второй поработали, отпустили.

Comment: >>>например у вас есть два Map с которым вы работаете. Взяли блокировку по одному - поработали, отпустили, взяли второй поработали, отпустили.<<< не очень понял если честно, а нельзя ли пару строк кода? так вкратце...

Comment: смотрите ответ ниже